# visual studio Crystal report change zoom level ask for connection credentials

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I am using SAP crystal report for visual studio. When running for the first time it works fine with the datasource I set by runtime. But when I change the zoom level it prompts to enter database name, username and password. I am stuck on this for two days. Please help

[credentials prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rX18.png)

```
var resultData = GetExpenseData(fromDate, toDate);
ReportDocument document = new ReportDocument();
document.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reporting/ExpenseReport.rpt"));

document.SetDataSource(resultData);   

    ParameterDiscreteValue param1 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
param1.Value = fromDate;
ParameterDiscreteValue param2 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
param2.Value = toDate;

ParameterDiscreteValue param3 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
param3.Value = templeName;

ParameterFieldDefinitions fieldDefinitions = document.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
ParameterFieldDefinition fromDateFieldLocation = document.DataDefinition.ParameterFields[0];
ParameterValues fromDateParameterValues = fromDateFieldLocation.CurrentValues;
fromDateParameterValues.Add(param1);
fromDateFieldLocation.ApplyCurrentValues(fromDateParameterValues);

ParameterFieldDefinition toDateFieldLocation = document.DataDefinition.ParameterFields[1];
ParameterValues toDAteParameterValues = toDateFieldLocation.CurrentValues;
toDAteParameterValues.Add(param2);
toDateFieldLocation.ApplyCurrentValues(toDAteParameterValues);

ParameterFieldDefinition templeFieldLocation = document.DataDefinition.ParameterFields[2];
ParameterValues templeParameterValues = templeFieldLocation.CurrentValues;
templeParameterValues.Add(param3);
templeFieldLocation.ApplyCurrentValues(templeParameterValues);                       

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = document;
```

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Report need to Login:

See this [link](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-dynamic-login.htm).